# Meaning/usage of なめるな

Tags: usage

I have been struggling to find a meaning for なめるな. The word seems to have the effect of asking people to shut up, but this is just a guess.

It appears in a [news story about someone's twitter comment](http://getnews.jp/archives/111530), from last year.

The last few bits of the comment are:

```
いつもいつも私の仲間に迷惑なツイートをしてくる人に言います。私の何を知っている。なめるな
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the nuance of 'いつもいつも' and '迷惑' and the tone of '私の何を知っている。', I'd rather say it's the same as 馬鹿にするな = ふざけるな = Don't fuck with me' http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=don%27t+fuck+with+me

Answer (score 7):

According to edict, the third definition of `なめる` is "to make fun of, to make light of, to put down, to treat with contempt", so "don't make fun of me". [Space ALC defines](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA/UTF-8/) `なめるなよ` as "Don't monkey around with me."

Answer (score 4):

an other meaning of なめる is to look down on someone, to underestimate in a condescendant way.